# Javascript auto popup (without clicking a button)

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I was just wondering if it is possible to display a javascript message (either popup or something nice) which is triggered by something which isn't a mouse click, so for example:

```
<?php if(a == b) {
    Then auto pop up something
}
```

I have had a look around and cant seem to find anything, also how do people make like stylistic popups like.. i guess maybe CSS but really fancy ones which cant be done with CSS any ideas?

Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Really fancy pop up boxes can most certainly done with CSS.  It's just really fancy CSS ;)

Comment: The really fancy popup boxes are called 'modal dialogs'. Google it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a script block to open an alert or what ever you need to open

```
<?php if(a == b) { ?>
    <script>
          alert('hello');
          // or
          window.open("http://wwwstackoverflow.com");
          // or any type of script you want to run

    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @Gabe: Well you fixed some of it now. You still don't close your PHP codeblock or `echo` the inner part.

Comment: @Purmou, actually I just used the OP's block, fixed that and the mismatch of double quotes within a minute of my post. Ease off, it didn't warrant an ambigious comment. If you choose to comment, be clear.

Comment: @IanGarratt - NP, please don't forget to mark it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Gabe: That script tag still doesn't make sense there without an `echo` or `?>`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here these days: `window.open()` called like that will be blocked by any modern browser.

If you're okay with including [a third-party script](https://github.com/colorfulfool/rails-popup), you can do this instead:

```
<?php if(a == b) { ?>
  <script>
    Popup("<div>Hello</div>").show('up')
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```